# Splitting a normal extension into a purely inseparable and a separable extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I would like to prove the following statement.

> Let $E/F$ be a normal field extension of finite degree and $K=\mathrm{Fix}(\mathrm{Gal}(E/F))$. Then $K/F$ is purely inseparable. (By the way, $E/K$ is Galois, for which I have a proof).

I started like this:
If $F=K$, this statement is trivial. So let $F \neq K$.

Let
$$L=\{\alpha \in K \mid \alpha \mbox{ is separable over } F\}.$$
We know that $L$ is an intermediate field of $F$ and $K$. We would like to prove that $L=F$.
Clearly $L \neq K$, otherwise $E/F$ would be separable and normal, and therefore Galois. Then $K=\mathrm{Fix}(\mathrm{Gal}(E/F))=F$, what we excluded.

I don't know how to continue the proof. Any help?

Comment: Pick $\alpha \in L$ and look at its minimal polynomial. What happens to it over $E$. If it has degree greater than $1$ can you find an automorphism that swaps $\alpha$ with another root of its minimal polynomial?

Comment: $E/F$ is not separable, so what do you mean by $K = \text{Fix}(\text{Gal}(E/F))$?

Comment: Presumably that $K$ is the set of points fixed by each $F$-automorphism of $E$.

Comment: $Gal(E/F)$ is defined as all $F$-automorphisms of $E$ that fix $F$.

Comment: Ok - I would have reserved that for the case that $E/F$ is actually Galois, and used $\text{Aut}(E/F)$ otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem.

Let $\alpha \in L \setminus F$. Call $f$ the minimal polynomial of $f$. The degree of f is greater than 2, otherwise $\alpha \in F$. Because $E$ is normal, $f$ splits over $E$. Now, we use the following two theorems.

Let $E/F$ be a normal field extension of finite degree, than E is the splitting field of a polynomial $g \in F[x]$.

Let $E/F$ be a field extension and $G=Gal(E/F)(=Aut(E/F))$. Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial and $\Omega=\{\beta \in E \mid f(\beta)=0 \} \neq \emptyset $. If $E$ is the splitting field of a polynomial $g \in F[x]$, the action of $G$ on $\Omega$ is transitive.

With these two theorems a find an $F$-automorphism of $E$ that swaps two roots of our minimal polynomial $f$. This strives with the fact that $L \subset Fix(Gal(E/F))$. Therefor, we cannot take an $\alpha \in L \setminus F$ and thus $F=L$.

Can someone confirm my proof is correct?

Comment: Yes, this reasoning is fine

Comment: (Other than a few typos: in the conclusion of the first theorem, you want that $E$ is a splitting field)